# Can I hide running applications from the unity launcher?

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook, customization, dock

When running UNE 10.10 I often have several applications running which on a traditional GNOME desktop environment would be running purely in the background and would only be visible from the system tray.  Good examples would be tomboy when hidden or [redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/).

Unfortunately Unity shows a running application in the launcher (dock) for these applications even though they already have appindicators visible in the sys tray.

Is there any way to configure/force Unity not to show icons in the dock for certain applications?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it with Unity myself, but you should be able to use [Devil's Pie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/) to hide them.